# Is there a better way to record the value of an attribute every day?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, performance, cron

I have a model `Thing` with an attribute `rating` that will change over time. I want to be able to look up what the value of any `Thing.rating` was on a given date.

For example, if `@thing = Thing.first` and `@thing.rating` was equal to `5` on January 13 2015, I want to be able to return that value on any future date.

One idea I had was to create a new model called `ThingPast`, which would belong_to `Thing`, and `Thing` would have_many_of `ThingPast`. `ThingPast` would have the attributes `thing_id`, `rating`, and `date_created`. Every day at a certain time, a Cron job would create a `ThingPast` for every `Thing`, and just copy the `rating` attribute.

I think this would technically work, but it seems unnecessarily complicated and inefficient. Does anyone know of a better, simpler way to accomplish this?

Comment: I think what you've described is the most logical method, I'll be very interested to hear any alternative suggestions. Only one comment from me would be to perhaps change the name from `ThingPast` to `ThingRating`. You're recording values of the present as well as the past, and you're recording `Ratings` for a `Thing` - so may as well have an obvious name that reflects exactly that. 
I think so long as you index the `thing_id` you'll be fine with this approach.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- Add a `ratings` table with columns `rating`, `thing_id` and `created_at`, and an index on `thing_id` and `created_at`.
- Remove the `rating` field from `Thing` and replace it with

  ```
  has_many :ratings, order: 'created_at desc'
  ```
- Save each new or changed rating as a new record in the `ratings` table, e.g. with an `after_save` callback.
- Add a method to `Thing` like:

  ```
  def rating_at(rating_time)
    ratings.where("created_at <= ?", rating_time).first.try(:rating)
  end
  ```
- And to replace the missing field:

  ```
  def rating
    ratings.first.try(:rating)
  end
  ```

Now if you want daily ratings you can iterate over dates and call `rating_at` for each:

```
    (1..10).map { |days_ago| thing.rating_at(days_ago.days.ago) }.sort
```

No cron job needed.

Comment: This is a better solutions, because if you really thing about it, `rating` always associated with a date(time), and `thing` can have multiple `ratings` over the time.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `paper_trail` gem https://github.com/airblade/paper_trail; it keeps versions of your model. It stores all versions of models that you choose in a `versions` table with polymorphic relation to your models.

You can get the daily version you want by querying the versions table

```
PaperTrail::Version.where(item: Thing.first, created_at: Date.yesterday)
```

which will get you the model version at that date

Comment: Do you know if using this gem would use up more or less database memory than creating a new set of objects every day?

Comment: This gem will create a new database table `versions` and add to it a new record whenever the model changes. So I think it is the same as creating new objects every day only a more generic solution